# Kotlin spinners in fragments using

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, spinner

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm just trying to figure out how to use spinners in a fragment.

So I guess the code below is how I should initialize the spinner but how do I point this to my premade strings in R.array and how do I capture the selections on button click. Thanks.

```
class paychart : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var paychartview: View

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        paychartview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paychart, container, false)
    }
val yearspinner = paychartview.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinneryear)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource`

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val paychartview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paychart, container, false)
        val spinner = paychartview.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinneryear)

        spinner?.adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity, R.array.string_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) as SpinnerAdapter
        spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object :AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
             override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                //..
             }

             override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                //..
             }
     }

    return paychartview         
}
```